# Oracle XE listener automatically stops after system restart

Tags: oracle, listener

I am using Oracle XE db and since yesterday my connection listener stops working so I receive the error: "The network adapter could not estabilish the connection" so every time I relog into windows I have to manually start the listener from cmd with the following command: lsnrctl start
How can I set it to auto-start at system startup?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Control panel, open Administrative tools, Services and set OracleXEListener to start **Automatically**.